# How to add a virtual column with the schema builder?

Tags: laravel, mariadb

I'm creating a table like this,

```
Schema::create('booking_segments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->datetime('start')->index();
    $table->integer('duration')->unsigned();
    $table->string('comments');
    $table->integer('booking_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('booking_id')->references('id')->on('bookings')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

But I want to add one extra column. It looks like this in raw SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE booking_segments ADD COLUMN `end` DATETIME AS (DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL duration MINUTE)) PERSISTENT AFTER `start`
```

How can I add it in my migration? I will also need to create an index on it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but there is a way to do it using the schema builder since Laravel 5.3, so I thought I would put it here for completeness.

You can use laravel 5.3 [column modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#column-modifiers) virtualAs or storedAs.

So, to create a virtual generated column to be computed at every query you would create the column like this:

```
$table->dateTime('created_at')->virtualAs( 'DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL duration MINUTE)' );
```

To create a stored generated column you would create the column like this instead:

```
$table->dateTime('created_at')->storedAs( 'DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL duration MINUTE)' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with the schema builder (someone please correct me if I'm wrong) but you can always "fall back" to raw SQL:

```php
DB::statement('
    ALTER TABLE booking_segments
    ADD COLUMN `end` DATETIME AS (DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL duration MINUTE)) PERSISTENT AFTER `start`
');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Laravel Events to achieve the same result without using
storedAs or virtualAs.
For reference: [Laravel: performing some task on every insert/update when using Query Builder or Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398489/laravel-performing-some-task-on-every-insert-update-when-using-query-builder-or)

This is how i've done it:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /** .... **/

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($option) {
            $option->column1 = $option->column2 + 2;
        });

        static::updating(function ($option) {
            $option->column1 = $option->column2 + 2;
        });
    }
}
```