# Laravel 5.5 - How to create a `negative_id` column value based on `id` value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-migrations

I am doing a test, but not sure how to do it with laravel migration file. In short, there is the auto incrementing `id` field (which will always be a positive integer). But I also want a `negative_id` field, which would be the value of `id * -1`, and would be automatically inserted in sync when an `id` is inserted to the database. So when the first user is added, `id` is automatically added as `1` so `negative_id` should be added as `-1` for that row, since `1 * -1 = -1`. The table should look like this:

```
| id | negative_id 
------------------
| 1  | -1                   
| 2  | -2                   
| 3  | -3
```

Below is my current migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('negative_id'); // how to make this id*-1 value
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

Any idea how to accomplish this from the migration file?

Comment: I think, you can try triggers.(if we talk about the database level). On the other hand, you can use `Eloquent` events [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Generated columns

```
$table->integer('negative_id')->virtualAs('id*-1');
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162018/8541805) link for more info.

Comment: Hmmm... When I add that to migration and migrate I get `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3109 Generated column 'negative_id' cannot refer to auto-increment column.`