# Laravel Auth User add custom data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

We are currently working on an application with a Google Login with Laravel with Socialite. We have a Auth user who gets a permission number ex. 264. We have made a function which returns an array with all binary numbers this permission number is made off.

Because calling this function every single time a page loads may be kinda heavy, we thought of adding this once when the Auth::user() is created. We thought of adding a custom constructor in the Model, but we can't make it work.

```
function __construct($attributes = array()) {
  parent::__construct($attributes);
  $this->permissionsArray = PermissionHelper::permissionConverter($this->permissions);
}
```

But we can't get it to work, `$this` doesn't have values when calling this function.

TLDR;
Directly after making the Auth user I want to call the permissionConverter function and save the data to the user so we can use it more often. Any suggestions on how to do this?

EDIT: I checked all answers out today, succeeded with one of them, but I assumed Laravel put the authenticated user in the SESSION or something. I found out it doesn't and it gets all the data from the database every request. We couldn't do what we requested for unfortunately. So I just had to refactor the script and make it as efficient as possible (although it became a bit less readable for less experienced programmers).

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949698/7065748

Create a on the `User` Eloquent model a `boot` method with

```
class User extends BaseModel {
  public static function boot() {
    static::creating(function($model) {
      $model->permissionsArray = PermissionHelper::permissionConverter($model->permissions);
    });
    // do the same for update (updating) if necessary
  }
}
```

---

Can't you just use this method ?

If new user:

```
$user = new User(); // or User:create(['...']) directly
$user->name = 'toto';
// and all other data
```

or

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

then

```
$user->permissionsArray = PermissionHelper::permissionConverter($user->permissions);
$user->save();
```