# When does the laravel model attributes array gets populated?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, eloquent

We use a laravel application for our server site restful application. We have a MySql database that we store our data. To access data we use laravel models. Sometimes we might need to create custom attributes or manipulate attributes using accessors and mutators.
Here's the thing. Sometimes we need to calculate data, using accessors, from multiple attributes. For example, if the table contains a field called due_date and we would like to define a custom attribute to indicate if the due date has passed or not, we use a custom attribute like the following:

```
protected $appends = array('is_late');

public function getIsLateAttribute()
{
    return (Carbon::now() > Carbon::parse($this->attributes['due_date']));
}
```

My question is: is it guaranteed that the attributes array will be filled at the point where we get the due_date attribute? When the attribute gets populated in the Model's lifecycle? Will be also safe to use if we need to access attributes from an accessor of an existing database field?

Thank you.

Comment: Might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398489/laravel-performing-some-task-on-every-insert-update-when-using-query-builder-or

Comment: I looked into that, I don't think it relates to what I'm asking. Thank you anyways. :)

Comment: The question is still unanswered. The only proposal below does not fully answer the question. It only says that `$attributes` is guaranteed to be set when the object is going to be converted to an array. However, it does not answer when the array is set. I had the problem that an accessor sometimes gets called by the framework when the `$attributes` is not yet set. This happens for accessor of attributes that actually exist as columns in the database. Those accessor have a single parameter and the framework passes the DB value to the method, but the question is where does this value come from?

Answer (score 3):

The **$attributes** property is filled with model's data when model is loaded from the database. So the moment you get access to a model object all attributes are already set.

Attributes listed in **$appends** variable, on the other hand, are appended when existing model is converted into an array, so you can safely assume that **$attributes** are already set by then.